# What was the reason for Jesus choosing the purification jars for his miracle at Cana?

Tags: gospel-of-john, miracles, ritual

We read in John 2 how Jesus performed his first miracle :

> On the third day there was a wedding in Cana of Galilee, and the mother of Jesus was there.   Jesus and his disciples had also been invited to the wedding.   When the wine gave out, the mother of Jesus said to him, “They have no wine.”   And Jesus said to her, “Woman, what concern is that to you and to me? My hour has not yet come.”   His mother said to the servants, “Do whatever he tells you.”   Now standing there were six stone water jars for the Jewish rites of purification, each holding twenty or thirty gallons.   Jesus said to them, “Fill the jars with water.” And they filled them up to the brim.

In the same chapter, we see Jesus cleansing the Temple, not with water, but by driving out the undesirable elements (vs 13-16) .

Going back to Cana, one feels that there was a reason for Jesus selecting the  purification jars for turning them into wine-containers . He could have very well used the wine jars that had been emptied , but he didn't. My question therefore,  is: What was the reason for Jesus choosing the  purification jars for his miracle at Cana ? Inputs from any denomination are welcome.

Comment: Without any authoritative references, my initial thought here is that the purification jars are used for washing and making clean, the wine is a symbol of His blood (later the wine *is* His blood), and we are washed clean by His blood.

Comment: Might be better placed on Biblical Hermeneutics SE